# moment.tz(date:string,timezone:string) VS moment.utc(date:string).tz(timezone:string)

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm struggling to see the difference between these two lines.
Is there any ?

```
const date1 = moment
  .utc("2021-12-07T10:00:00")
  .tz("Europe/London")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");

const date2 = moment
  .tz("2021-12-07T10:00:00", "Europe/London")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");

console.log(date1); // "2021-12-07T10:00:00+00:00"
console.log(date2); // "2021-12-07T10:00:00+00:00"
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/tan-aki/pen/QWMwRqw?editors=1112

Thank you !

Comment: What difference do you expect there to be?

Comment: OK maybe the question wasn't properly formulated, they indeed achieve the same objective, it's a given. But is there a difference in the way the objective is being achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is difference with this syntax. Before explaining the difference, we should look at the timezone and the time given.

**Timezone**: Europe/London

**Time**: 2021-12-07T10:00:00

For London in December, DST (Daylight saving time) is not effective. So, the zone will be GMT +0 (UTC).

In order to see the difference, we should take a date value when DST is effective.

Consider 2021-09-07T10:00:00

```js
const date1 = moment
  .utc("2021-09-07T10:00:00")
  .tz("Europe/London")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");

const date2 = moment
  .tz("2021-09-07T10:00:00", "Europe/London")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");

console.log(date1); // "2021-12-07T11:00:00+01:00"
console.log(date2); // "2021-12-07T10:00:00+01:00"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

The hour of `date1` is 11 when `date2`'s is 10.

`date1` explanation:

1. moment considers "2021-09-07T10:00:00" in UTC -> "2021-09-07T10:00:00+00:00"
2. The time is converted to `Europe/London` zone -> "2021-09-07T11:00:00+01:00"
3. Formatted string -> "2021-09-07T11:00:00+01:00"

`date2` explanation:

1. moment consider "2021-09-07T10:00:00" in Europe/London -> "2021-09-07T10:00:00+01:00"
2. Formatted string -> "2021-09-07T10:00:00+01:00"

Let's try with formatting string including zone information

```js
const date1 = moment
  .utc("2021-09-07T10:00:00Z")
  .tz("Europe/London")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");

const date2 = moment
  .tz("2021-09-07T10:00:00Z", "Europe/London")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ");
  
console.log(date1); // "2021-12-07T11:00:00+01:00"
console.log(date2); // "2021-12-07T11:00:00+01:00"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

See. When constructing times with `tz()`; if there is no zone information in the string, zone information is just applied. Otherwise, the date is converted to the corresponding zone. In such case, the date is increased or decreased depending on the zone (1 hour is added for Europe/London).

`date1` and `date2` in the last snippet is equivalent but, you should be careful about zone information, formatting. Always try to include zone information if you are converting between different zones. It is also good to pass formatting string to the constructor. It greatly decreases the chance of failure.